# How to apply dplyr function to a list and not remove list attribute

Tags: r, list, dplyr

There is list `ori_list` , I want to apply `dplyr` function `mutate select` and `scale` to the list and not remove list attribute (I guess ,maybe this will be more faster than manipulate a combined dataframe). But below code faile . Anyone can help ?

```
 new_list <- ori_list %>% mutate(value_amount = value + amount,value_new = scale(value)) %>% 
      select(cat_1,value_amount)
```

the whole code as below :

```
   library(tidyverse)
    d1 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','b','c','c'),
                     value = c(1,2,3,4),
                     amount = c(7,6,5,4))
    d2 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','b','e','c'),
                     value = c(1,1,3,4),
                     amount = c(7,6,7,4))
    d3 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','e','c','c'),
                     value = c(1,2,8,4),
                     amount = c(7,2,5,4))
    
    
    ori_list <- list(d1,d2,d3)
    
    new_list <- m_list %>% mutate(value_amount = value + amount,value_new = scale(value)) %>% 
      select(cat_1,value_amount)
```

Comment: `m_list` & and `ori_list` should be the same?

Comment: right , just wrong type in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still need to iterate through those list items to apply `mutate` / `select` pipeline on each individual dataframe , i.e. with `lapply` or `purrr::map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
d1 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','b','c','c'),
                 value = c(1,2,3,4),
                 amount = c(7,6,5,4))
d2 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','b','e','c'),
                 value = c(1,1,3,4),
                 amount = c(7,6,7,4))
d3 <- data.frame(cat_1 = c('a','e','c','c'),
                 value = c(1,2,8,4),
                 amount = c(7,2,5,4))

ori_list <- list(d1,d2,d3)

ori_list %>% 
  map( \(df) mutate(df, value_amount = value + amount,value_new = scale(value)) %>% 
             select(cat_1,value_amount))
#> [[1]]
#>   cat_1 value_amount
#> 1     a            8
#> 2     b            8
#> 3     c            8
#> 4     c            8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   cat_1 value_amount
#> 1     a            8
#> 2     b            7
#> 3     e           10
#> 4     c            8
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   cat_1 value_amount
#> 1     a            8
#> 2     e            4
#> 3     c           13
#> 4     c            8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks . What's the purpose  of  '\(df)' ? Thanks!

Comment: `map` expects a function for it's 2nd argument and `\(df) ... `  is a shorthand for anonymous function,  `\(x) x + 1`  is same as `function(x) x + 1`